List of words starting with vowels
This would be useful to automatically add “a” or “an” in front of the word. In software converting text to speech it would help pronouncing “the” correct, for example “the healthy man” vs. “The honest man”.
I tried finding such a list using Google. I found one list of 1000 words starting with vowels which is quite useless, for example “uniformed” vs. “uninformed”.
What would be most useful would be a set of general rules, which might cover 95% of cases, plus a list of exceptions. Especially important would be words like “heir” which are spoken different by different people, or SQL like SQL which has two different “official” pronunciations - “sequel” or “ess-queue-ell”.

You need a list of words with their pronunciation, i.e. a pronunciation dictionary.

One can quite reliably create such a list for oneself: if the following word is spoken with an initial vowel sound, then the form of the indefinite article to use is an, and the is pronounced with a vowel like the one in the verb beat; if instead the following word is spoken with an initial consonant sound, then the indefinite article is a, and the is pronounced with a vowel something like the one in the verb butt.

Who says heir with an initial consonant sound? Are you thinking of hare?

I know people who would make heir sound very similar to hare.

Get a dictionary with pronunciations. The examine the pronunciations. Figure out which letters or symbols in their pronunciation guide make a consonant versus a vowel sound.
I don't know of a simple rule that would tell you that "uniformed" starts with a consonant sound while "uninformed" starts with a vowel sound. I think most English speakers just memorize them. A rule of thumb would be that if it starts with a vowel other than "u", it probably starts with a vowel sound, and if it starts with a consonant other than "x" or "y", it probably starts with a consonant sound. The simplest rule in practice would probably be that if it starts with a vowel, assume a vowel sound, if it starts with a consonant, counting "y" as a consonant, assume a consonant sound. Then have a list of exceptions. I'm not sure how many words would be on the exception list but probably less than a hundred. Not thousands or millions.

In that case, you have a prefix un- and a different prefix uni-  For uninformed you could conclude that the prefix cannot be uni- because then nformed would have to be a word, and words don’t start with nf.

@gnasher729 That thinking works in this case. But would it work as a universal rule? Maybe it's possible to come up with a set of rules that would handle all cases. But how long and complicated would such a list of rules have to be? At some point you'd be making up rules that only apply to one word, at which point you might as well just say "this word is an exception to the rules".
